# How do I import a list from a function in an imported file?

Tags: python, list, function

I am attempting to create an RPG game and I am making the code more concise. I have come across a problem that I can't resolve, and I have also done some research on it, but I can't seem to fix it.

I have my main code as `DragonFightingRPG.py` with my other files that I am importing in the same directory (`prints.py` and `options.py`).
I am trying to import a list from another file, so it can check whether the user has inputted one of those answers, and it can answer accordingly.

**DragonFightingRPG.py**

```
import prints
import options

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.gold = None
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.health = 100

    def get_name(self):
        self.name = input("Hey there! What's your name?\n~~> ")
        print("Nice name, {0}!".format(self.name))

    def give_gold(self):
        print("Since you are new around here, 100 gold doubloons have been given to you!")
        self.gold = 100

    def gold_counter(self):
        print("You currently have {0} gold!".format(player.gold))



player = Player()


def start():
    player.get_name()
    player.give_gold()
    gold_counter()
    prints.intro()


def gold_counter():
    while True:
        option = input("Do you want to see your balance?\n~~> ").upper()
        if option in {options.yes_opt}:
            print("You currently have {0} gold.".format(player.gold))
        elif option in {options.no_opt}:
            print("You can check your balance later in the game.")
        else:
            print("Please try again.")
            continue
        break





start()
```

**prints.py**

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.gold = None
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.health = 100

    def get_name(self):
        self.name = input("Hey there! What's your name?\n~~> ")
        print("Nice name, {0}!".format(self.name))

    def give_gold(self):
        print("Since you are new around here, 100 gold doubloons have been given to you!")
        self.gold = 100

    def gold_counter(self):
        print("You currently have {0} gold!".format(player.gold))

def intro():
    print("Narrator: Uhhhm...")
    print("N: Let me check my list...")
    print("N: Ah! Yes! {0}, that's right. I heard you were supposed to be arriving today.".format(player.name))
    print("N: Welcome to... THE DRAGON FIGHTER GAME!")
    print("N: I know, it isn't the most imaginative name.")
    print("N: Don't look at me like that, I tried my hardest!")
    print("N: Anywho, let's carry on.")
    print("N: For some stupid reason, the creator of this game didn't give me an actual name, so\nmy name is just \"Narrator\" or \"N\".")
    print("N:")

player = Player()
```

**options.py**

```
def yes_opt():
    {"Y", "YE", "YES", "YEAH", "PLEASE", "YES PLEASE"}

def no_opt():
    {"N", "NO", "NOPE"}
```

The part I am struggling with is `elif option in {options.no_opt}:` and `if option in {options.yes_opt}:`. It works if I just have the list typed out in the main code, but I want to try and get it imported from the other file. Any thoughts?

Comment: When you want the list imported, why are you putting it in a function? What's wrong with `yes_opt = {"Y", "YE", "YES", "YEAH", "PLEASE", "YES PLEASE"}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> def yes_opt():
>     {"Y", "YE", "YES", "YEAH", "PLEASE", "YES PLEASE"}
> ```

This defines a *function* called `yes_opt` (which effectively does nothing), not a *set* with that name.

Therefore, `option in yes_opt` does not work.

You probably meant to simply write this instead:

```
yes_opt = {"Y", "YE", "YES", "YEAH", "PLEASE", "YES PLEASE"}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a few small changes, you can get this working.

1. `options.py`

You should return these sets from the methods.

```
def yes_opt():
    return {"Y", "YE", "YES", "YEAH", "PLEASE", "YES PLEASE"}

def no_opt():
    return {"N", "NO", "NOPE"}
```

2. In `DragonFightingRPG.py`, you specify `from options import yes_opt, no_opt` as an import statement.

When you call these functions, they'll return the appropriate set.

```
if option in yes_opt():
```

And so on.